# Scan big Aztec-Codes in Android App

Tags: java, android, zxing, aztec-barcode

I'm trying to scan big aztec codes within my android application. The first choice here of course is Zxing, because it's free and easy to integrate.

The problem is, that Zxing fails during scanning bigger aztec codes. Symbologies greater than 71x71 modules fail nearly everytime. There are several issues on github, but nobody ever solved this problem reliable and I dont have the knowledge for doing this.

My question is, whether someone here knows a simple, lib or app to integrate with intents which scans bigger aztec codes (such on UIC railway tickets for e.g.) reliable? 
And yes, it should be free or should at least have a cheaper option, because this is only for experimenting and trying some things - I could imagine to pay maybe $ 200-300, but not > $ 2,000 only for a developer license, which exceeds within one year!

That means NeoReader - as well as it's working with aztec codes - is out of scope for me, as well as the Leadtools SDK.

Does anybody know solution for this problem or do you think it's impossible to do?

Greetings

Comment: A correction regarding our LEADTOOLS. It does not cost $2,000 for barcode modules. Our Barcode Pro v19 is currently priced at $1,295 so if you don't need some of the more expensive features like medical imaging, you only pay that. It also does not expire after a year. Once you buy it, you can keep using it forever, provided it's for the same application you deployed it with. Finally, if you only need "experimenting and trying some things", our evaluation has no strings attached. It gives you 2 months with all SDK features enabled for free. If you don't want it after that, simply uninstall it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the 
[Google's mobile vision API](https://developers.google.com/vision/android/barcodes-overview)

The library mentioned below, uses the google's mobile vision API and does the boilerplate code for you.

[Androidhive barcode-reader](https://github.com/ravi8x/Barcode-Reader)

Comment: Seems like a possible solution - I'll check that soon, thank you!

Comment: Okay it just works that way, but much better than Zxing. I only tried building the app you mentioned in your second link, this reads the barcode at least - now I only have to get Byte-data from the Scanner but that should be possibly anyway :-)

Comment: Okay I've got another question, I knew there must be any issue which makes it impossible to use the library as it is... The Mobile Vision API doesn't provide any possibility to get the raw binary data as byte[] from a barcode. I need exactly this, cause the barcodes I want to decode contain mostly binary data. It's also impossible for me to change the barcode-content, because this is an international standard and I don't think they'll change that for me. Do you know any possibility to achieve this problem...? Override sth in the lib? But I can't find any source code anywhere...

Answer (score 2):

I have spent some hours under this issue and via lots of testing I found it that when you put a white border around the aztec code, then it works quite well and fast :-) I use it in my app:

```
 //for the barcode bitmap (string) scanning:
 implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3'
 //FOR THE CAMERA SCANNING:
 implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.0.0'
```

Comment: Sounds great and works great indeed! The white border was already around my aztec codes, when I asked the question in january '17, since im working with online tickets of Deutsche Bahn. They didn't change their format, but it seems like Zxing received an update fixing the issue with aztec codes :-)
I had given up on this, if you hadn't written an answer here, I never would have tried again :-) Thank you!